# What is the reference system for depth data in the TangoXYZij Class?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I report what is writtein in the documentation :

IntPtr xyz
An array of packed coordinate triplets, x,y,z as floating point values.

With the unit in landscape orientation, screen facing the user: +Z points in the direction of the camera's optical axis, and is measured perpendicular to the plane of the camera. +X points toward the user's right, and +Y points toward the bottom of the screen. The origin is the focal centre of the color camera. The output is in units of metres.

I have a little doubt about the sentence: "is measured perpendicular to the plane of the camera", that is referred to the z coordinate. Does it mean that the measure is taken from the plane of the camera (near clipping plane) or from the camera itself?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is reference [this page](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/coordinate-systems), "On-Device Coordinate Frames" section. By the device design convention of Tango device, the depth camera coordinate is same as color camera.